# Why can't ImageTransformation be parallelized?

Tags: image-processing, parallelization

I have a rather [complicated code](https://pastebin.com/WUGMnMm3) for an [ImageTransformation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageTransformation.html), which would benefit from some acceleration. Since every pixel is independend of every other, I tried [Parallelize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html), which, in a simplified form, would look like

```
pic = Import["http://666kb.com/i/dsfr4u76175v8q277.png"]
Parallelize[ImageTransformation[pic, Sin]]
```

but it only gives me the error message

> ImageTransformation[...] cannot be parallelized; proceeding with sequential evaluation

However, when I split the [PlotRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) manually, for example, into four quadrants, which I render simultaneously on four kernels, the whole job only takes 1/4 of the time, because each kernel has only 1/4 of the pixels to render, and the CPU is at 100% as it should be.

I'd expect [Parallelize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html) to do the same thing, but it doesn't; on my four kernel machine only one kernel is used. The CPU is therefore only at 25% — so the whole job takes four times longer than nescessary.

Is there a way to get the same effect automatically, so that I don't have to split the [PlotRange](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html) manually, and submit the calculation to four different .nb-Files (or, as many as there are available kernels on my machine) every time, and then join the four parts of the resulting image with [ImageAssemble](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageAssemble.html)?

With four kernels, it's not that bad, but if I were to work on a 16 kernel machine, it would be a nuissance to do the breakdown every time to get the speed up. Perhaps [Parallelize](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Parallelize.html) it the wrong way to do it. Is there is a better way to achieve the parallelization?

Comment: The documentation says that "`Parallelize` distributes different parts of expr..." In your case, there is only one part, so there is nothing to distribute. You have a more general notion of what you think `Parallelize` should do, but it isn't what it does. I think splitting the image into parts like you did is a good way to do it, you could write a function to do that automatically.

Comment: But since every pixel needs a different integration time, it would be better to have Mathematica distributing the next pixel to the next available Kernel as soon as the previous pixel is finished, is there really no built in command for that? If I split them manually there are always some parts that take longer than the others, while functions like Parallelize, if they would work here, could do a fine or coarse graining, depending on the problem.

Comment: I'm now confused about why it works to split the image into four. In general that shouldn't produce the same result when using `ImageTransformation` on each quadrant, is there something special about your transformation function that ensures that this works?

Comment: Light rays don't gravitationally attract each other in this scenario, so every ray can be traced independend of each other.

Comment: You can always use `ImagePartition` to split the image up and then use a `ParallelTable` or `ParallelMap` to parallelize the transformation over the parts.

Comment: That splits up the source material. But every Kernel needs the same source file, the PlotRange that can be split up is not the DataRange of the source file but of the final image!